# Laravel ajax return 404

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send data to back-end and i'm getting 404 error with this explanation in network tab:

```
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

## Route

```
Route::middleware('verified')->group(function () {

   Route::post('/snaptoken/{id}', 'Admin\PayController@token')->name('securepaymentnow');
});
```

## Controller

```
public function token(Request $request, $id) 
    {
        //Find project
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

        //rest of data
    }
```

## Blade

```
//form and button
  <form id="payment-form" method="POST" action="{{route('securepaymentnow', $project->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="result_type" id="result-type" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="result_data" id="result-data" value="">
  </form>
  <button class="btn-sm bg-success pay-button" data-id="{{$project->id}}" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-fas fa-shield-alt"></i> Secure Payment</button>

//javascript

$('.pay-button').click(function (event) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var prdfoId = $(this).data('id');
          $.ajax({
            url: '{{url("/securepaymentnow")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) {
              var resultType = document.getElementById('result-type');
              var resultData = document.getElementById('result-data');
            }
          });
});
```

Any idea?

.........................................................................................................................

Comment: do you print the `$id` in your controller? and are you sure that Project with `$id` exists in db?

Comment: as I get this error i cannot get dd from back-end but in my network which returns error i get id 60 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `url()` function, you should use the `{{ url('/snaptoken') }}`.

But if you want to use the "name" from the "securepaymentnow", use `route()` function with this example `{{ route('securepaymentnow', $theId) }}`.

Both should works.

Refer [Laravel NamedRoute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) for details.

Comment: getting route in javascript is a bit hard and i'm using `url` based on your suggestion i already have `/` as ` url: '{{url("/securepaymentnow")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),`

Comment: it is not "/securepaymentnow". you wrote in your web.php as "/snaptoken", so replace it as "/snaptoken" in `url()` parameter

Comment: it is not "/securepaymentnow". you wrote in your web.php as "/snaptoken"